# Tastypie: How to exclude a Resource field from full_dehydrate results?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'd like to exclude one of my Resource fields from the data returned by the Resource's `full_dehydrate` method. I don't want to exclude the field from the Resource entirely using `excludes`, however, because I'd like to allow updates to the field via the API.

I tried setting the field's `use_in` attribute to a blank string but that did nothing and my Google searches have come up empty thus far. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your full_dehydrate method, you can do the following:

```
if 'field' in bundle.data.keys()
    del bundle.data['field']
return bundle
```